# Suppress part of the default constructor?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to suppress part of the default constructor initialization? My current default constructor looks like this:

```
Jd::Jd() {
    time_t utcTime = time(NULL);
    struct tm tmLocal;
    localtime_s( &tmLocal, &utcTime );

    jd_ = gregorian_to_jd( 
                        tmLocal.tm_year + 1900, 
                        tmLocal.tm_mon + 1, 
                        tmLocal.tm_mday,
                        tmLocal.tm_hour,
                        tmLocal.tm_min,
                        tmLocal.tm_sec
                          );
}
```

And I am using two constants to initialize my Jd objects: WTIMEOFDAY and NOTIMEOFDAY.

```
Jd const NOTIMEOFDAY;
Jd const WTIMEOFDAY;
```

I want NOTIMEOFDAY to be initialized as a default constructed object but with only the year, month and day portions of the gregorian_to_jd() method instead of the whole thing. Is this possible?

EDIT: constructors in Jd class

```
Jd();
Jd( jdn_t jdn ) : jd_( jdn ) { } //Sets the internal datamember to whatever is passed in.
//Jd( bool includeTime );
```

And the error im getting is:

```
error C2668: 'calendar::Jd::Jd' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
could be 'calendar::Jd::Jd(bool)
or       'calendar::Jd::Jd(calendar::jdn_t)
```

Comment: Sounds like creating a constructor that takes the arguments you want to pass in would do this, but it is a little unclear what you are asking since WTIMEOFDAY and NOTIMEOFDAY are nowhere in your example code.

Comment: Just set `tm_hour`, `tm_min`, and `tm_sec` to zero after calling `localtime()` (or just set those parameters in the `gregorian_to_jd()` function call to zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another constructor that takes the parameters:

```
Jd::Jd(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int min, int sec)
{
    jd_ = gregorian_to_jd(year, month, day, hour, min, sec);
}
```

When creating your constants:

```
const Jd NOTIMEOFDAY(2013, 10, 12, 0, 0, 0); // new constructor called
const Jd WTIMEOFDAY; // default constructor called
```

Or you can use this method:

```
Jd::Jd(bool includeTime = true) 
{
    time_t utcTime = time(NULL);
    struct tm tmLocal;
    localtime_s( &tmLocal, &utcTime );

    jd_ = gregorian_to_jd( 
                        tmLocal.tm_year + 1900, 
                        tmLocal.tm_mon + 1, 
                        tmLocal.tm_mday,
                        includeTime ? tmLocal.tm_hour : 0,
                        includeTime ? tmLocal.tm_min : 0,
                        includeTime ? tmLocal.tm_sec : 0);
}
```

And then initialize your constants:

```
const Jd NOTIMEOFDAY((bool)false);
const Jd WTIMEOFDAY;
```

Or ...

```
// this will allow your double version to work
Jd::Jd(jdn_t jdn, bool includeTime = true) 
{
    // assuming what jdn_t looks like, so you'd have to make some adjustments
    jd_ = gregorian_to_jd( 
                        jdn.tm_year + 1900, 
                        jdn.tm_mon + 1, 
                        jdn.tm_mday,
                        includeTime ? jdn.tm_hour : 0,
                        includeTime ? jdn.tm_min : 0,
                        includeTime ? jdn.tm_sec : 0);
}
```

Or ...

```
// this should fix the whole issue and is probably the better solution
class Jd
{
    // other members
public:
    explicit Jd(bool includeTime); // prevent implicit conversion
    explicit Jd(jdn_t jdn); // also prevents implicit conversion
};

Jd::Jd(bool includeTime) // no default parameter
{
    time_t utcTime = time(NULL);
    struct tm tmLocal;
    localtime_s( &tmLocal, &utcTime );

    jd_ = gregorian_to_jd( 
                        tmLocal.tm_year + 1900, 
                        tmLocal.tm_mon + 1, 
                        tmLocal.tm_mday,
                        includeTime ? tmLocal.tm_hour : 0,
                        includeTime ? tmLocal.tm_min : 0,
                        includeTime ? tmLocal.tm_sec : 0);
}
```

Comment: Problem with this is that I want the NOTIMEOFDAY constant to be initialized to the current date, I don't want to have to hardcode it.

Comment: Then call `time(NULL); localtime_s(...);` sometime before you initialize the constant and pass in those values.  Alternatively, you can add a default parameter to your default constructor ...

Comment: This conflicts with another constructor I have: `Jd( double jdn ) : jd_( jdn ) { }`

Comment: There is no conflict between a constructor that takes a `double` and one that takes a `bool` as long as you are passing in an actual `double` and `bool` to the constructor.  You can also use the keyword `explicit` to prevent conversion constructors from being called incorrectly.

Comment: Even with the explicit keyword I am getting ambiguous call errors that won't allow me to compile

Comment: What other constructors do you have declared and what is the exact compiler error you are getting?

Comment: Unless you are trying to do something like `const Jd a(0);` instead of `const Jd a(false)`, there should be no ambiguous call (there isn't when I compile the code in VS2012).  You can also force the cast to bool (which is unnecessary, but shown in the edit).

Comment: I am not sure why its saying ambiguous call. If i dont include the boolean constructor and just making a constant with false as its parameter list not only does it compile but it throws no errors when it runs and just returns zero. So I am at a loss as to why this is being problematic.

Comment: It is likely calling the `Jd::Jd(double)` constructor (since it is the only other non-default one after you remove the `bool` version) with `0` as the input (which is why you would get `0` as it's value).  Try it with the `bool` version and explicitly casting it:   `const Jd a((bool)false);`

Comment: While this works for this one particular instance, it causes issues with a whole bunch of Jd objects usingthe double constructor in a unit test.cpp I have. And I am not allowed to edit the unittests so they have to stay as is, so I'm not sure this method will work.

Comment: Another option is to add a default parameter to your `double` constructor ... edited.